# How to reference file resource in a JSF Application

Tags: java, web-applications, jsf, glassfish

I want to dynamically reference an XSD from a bean, how is this possible? I already added the XSD to the project, so it's located somewhere in the GlassFish domain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `ExternalContext`.

If you want to load the resource in the bean, do it via [getResource](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) or [getResourceAsStream](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)):

```
InputStream stream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
    .getResourceAsStream("/foo.xsd");
```

If you want to return a URL to the resource, use [getRequestContextPath](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestContextPath()) to get the path relative to the host root:

```
ExternalContext ext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
    .getExternalContext();
String path = ext.getRequestContextPath();
path += path.endsWith("/") ? "foo.xsd" : "/foo.xsd";
String url = ext.encodeResourceURL(path);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I've got it as an InputStream, and after that I was able to read the XSD through a BufferedReader-InputStreamReader combo :)