# Read text file in JSF WebContent folder

Tags: java, jsf, resourcebundle

Ok, so I am trying to retrieve and read a text file that is in a WebContent/resources/ folder in my JSF project and I have no idea how to get the relative path to if from my backing bean... Any Suggestions on how to go about retrieving and reading this file?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
((ServletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext()).getRealPath("/resources/")
```

will give you the file system path of the resources folder.

Answer (score 0):

You can read your file with resource functions as described in this answer :

[How to reference file resource in a JSF Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528201/how-to-reference-file-resource-in-a-jsf-application)

```
InputStream stream = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
.getResourceAsStream("/foo.xsd");
```